# the_content() not showing full posts in category template

Tags: categories, templates

i want to show the full posts in category archive page, i put the_content() in the category template (content.php)

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'entry' ); ?><?php echo et_fable_get_background(); ?>>
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <header class="entry-title">
        <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php else : ?>
            <h2>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2>
        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php //et_fable_post_meta(); ?>
        </header>

    <?php if ( ! is_single() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-content clearfix">
            <p><?php truncate_post( 900 ); ?></p>
        </div> <!-- .entry-content -->
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <footer class="entry-footer">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more"><span><?php esc_html_e( 'Read More', 'Fable' ); ?></span></a>
        </footer>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div> <!-- .container -->

    <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</article> <!-- .entry-->
```

the_content() not display full post in content.php, but in single.php (the details content page), it shows the full post, i'm wondering why same code not displaying the same thing

Comment: I think you want to replace `<p><?php truncate_post( 900 ); ?></p>` with `<?php the_content(); ?>`.

Comment: i had tried, not work.

Comment: are you sure your category archive template loads `content.php`?

Comment: yes sure, i had tried comment out something, it will not display

Comment: i had tried replace the truncated into "global $more;   $more = 1;     the_content(); ", but it will show "read more" link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
     <?php global $post; ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'entry' ); ?><?php echo et_fable_get_background(); ?>>
            <div class="container clearfix">
                <header class="entry-title">
                <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <h2>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>
                <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php //et_fable_post_meta(); ?>
                </header>

            <?php if ( ! is_single() ) : ?>
                <div class="entry-content clearfix">
                    <p><?php truncate_post( 900 ); ?></p>
                </div> <!-- .entry-content -->
                <?php //This is page id or post id
        $content_post = get_post($post->ID);
        echo $content = $content_post->post_content;

         ?>
                <footer class="entry-footer">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more"><span><?php esc_html_e( 'Read More', 'Fable' ); ?></span></a>
                </footer>

            <?php endif; ?>

            </div> <!-- .container -->

            <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?>



        </article> <!-- .entry-->
```

Comment: forgot some code please check my update code Add <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?>
 it to that loop too